# Pydash: how to find using a object: py_.collections.find(DATA, OBJECT)

Tags: python, lodash, pydash

In lodash I can use the syntax:
`find(ARRAY_OF_OBJECTS, OBJECT)`
This will return an object from the array if it meets the criteria of the passed object. In this case `OBJECT` would be e.g. `{ active: true, dimension: 'target' }`. The objects in the array would contain e.g. `active`, `dimension`, `status` etc.

How can I do the same in pydash? I know I can do `find(ARRAY_OF_OBJECTS, lambda x: x.active == True`, but the thing is, the object I pass is dynamically made. So sometimes it might not have `active` (as example)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I can do it with `is_match` from pydash. In a complete line of code it would become this. `target_data` is an array of objects and `source_row['dimensions']` is an object

`py_.collections.find(target_data, lambda x: py_.predicates.is_match(x, source_row['dimensions']))`